# FullCalendar: I can't resize events in month view

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I get an event list from server with an AJAX call. I have the "editable" option set to "true", but it only works in agendaDay and agendaWeek views, not in month view. Why? This is the code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            right: "agendaDay,agendaWeek,month prev,next"
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        contentHeight: 700,
        timeFormat: "HH:mm",
        displayEventEnd: {
            month: false,
            agendaWeek: false,
            agendaDay: false,
            'default':true
        },
        axisFormat: "HH:mm",
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        editable: true,

        eventSources: [
            {   // 1st group: Miscellanea
                events: function(start,end,timezone,callback){

                    callAjax("Miscellanea",callback);
                },
                color: "#086A87",

            },{ // 2nd group: project init
                events: function(start,end,timezone,callback){

                    callAjax("Project",callback);
                },
                color: "#B40404"
            }
        ]
});
```

And this is my function callAjax:

```
function callAjax(type,callback){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/projects/{{project.id}}/get_events/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"data":type},
        success: function(response){
            data = eval("(" + response + ")")

            var events = [];

            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                events.push({
                    id: data[i].pk,
                    title: data[i].fields['title'],
                    start: data[i].fields['start'],
                    end: data[i].fields['end'],
                    className: "event",
                    defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:30:00"
                });
            }
            callback(events);
        }
    });

}
```

As I said before, all work fine except resizing in month view, and I can't imagine what's the problem. Help?

Comment: what is css in your .event class

Comment: Just font modifications:
.event{font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;}

Comment: Yes, i have! I write it below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to resize an event in month view, it has to be set as a "allday" event. To set an "allday" event, when getting the events from database, you have to differentiate them. I have a boolean column in the database called allday. Then, you set `allday` property depending on the value. This is how AJAX call differentiate them:

```
function callAjax(type,callback){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/projects/{{project.id}}/get_events/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"data":type},
        success: function(response){
            data = eval("(" + response + ")")

            var events = [];

            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                if(!data[i].fields['allday']){
                    events.push({
                        id: data[i].pk,
                        title: data[i].fields['title'],
                        start: data[i].fields['start'],
                        end: data[i].fields['end'],
                        className: "event",
                        defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:30:00"
                    });
                }else{
                    events.push({
                        id: data[i].pk,
                        title: data[i].fields['title'],
                        start: data[i].fields['start'],
                        end: data[i].fields['end'],
                        allDay: true,
                        className: "event",
                        defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:30:00"
                    });
                }
            }

            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

By default, "Allday" events start and finish at 0:00:00 of both days. Days don't need to be consecutive. "Allday" events can last more than one day. That's the reason you can resize them.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that you can't resize events on monthly view if `start` and `end`
have time info, only those that have date info:

```
{
    title: 'Resizable',
    start: '2015-02-11',
    end: '2015-02-13'
},
{
    title: 'Not resizable',
    start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
    end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
},
```

see [this bug report](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2441)

Answer (score 0):

Check you database, the allDay column. Me, I had it "null" or empty and had the same problem.
After changing the default value of the column from "NULL" to "0" and explicitly insert a "0" or a "1" in the allDay column, it started working.

Comment: Good [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) would improve the readability of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hcbofdun/3/)

You have to set `editable : true`, to make the event resizable.

But I have a fullcalendar demo running where I had to set both `allDay: true` and `editable : true`.

```
{
    title: 'Your Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
    end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
    allDay: true, // optional
    editable : true
}
```